# How to start a optionsmenu on a onclick event

Tags: android, onclick

Is it possible to set a optionsmenu on a onclick event? If yes how can I do this i dont find anything on the google documations... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Activity`-class has the [`openOptionsMenu()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29) which you can use.

Answer (score 1):

call this on onclick

```
openOptionsMenu();
```